# grep + fit grep syntax for solaris

Tags: linux, shell, grep, solaris

the target of the following grep command is to match numbers with "." (see example of PARAM that can be match and PARAM that should not match)

The problem is that this syntax work fine on Linux but not for Solaris

please advice how to fit this syntax for Solaris (or if someone have other opinion for other syntax that can work on both OS)

```
   echo $PARAM | grep  '^\([0-9]\+\.\)\+[0-9]\+$'
```

example of match PARAM

```
 PARAM=2.4
 PARAM=232.14
 PARAM=202.14.34
```

example of non match PARAM

```
 PARAM=2.
 PARAM=.14
 PARAM=202
 PARAM=2.a
 PARAM=e.14
 PARAM=202
```

Comment: Most Solaris boxes _I_ work on have GNU grep installed as `ggrep`. You could try that (often in /opt/csw/bin or thereabouts). If that works, I'll post as an answer

Comment: ggrep not found on my solaris machine (I have only grep)

Comment: Try `egrep` instead, but note that its syntax is different; in your case, all backslashes except before the dot should be removed.

Comment: yes very good now its work thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, that was an interesting task! Spent some time trying to figure out why my regular expressions work only partially in Solaris. Anyway, the trick is to use `egrep` instead of `grep`. You can refer to their manual pages to discover the following difference:

```
grep - search a file for a pattern
```

while:

```
egrep - search a file  for  a  pattern  using  full  regular expressions
```

I've noticed that on my RH system both `grep` and `egrep` have similar functionality:

```
grep, egrep, fgrep - print lines matching a pattern
```

For example, you can use the following solution:

```
echo $PARAM | egrep '^([0-9]+\.)+[0-9]+$'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `case` statement instead, although its syntax is not as versatile.

```
case $PARAM in
  *[!.0-9]* | *..* | .* | *. ) echo invalid ;;
  *) echo valid ;;
esac
```

In other words, anything with a character other than dot or number, or with two or more adjacent dots is invalid. **Edit**: Added leading or trailing dot to invalid case, too. Allow more than one dot.